# Bold String with underscore from spring mvc to .txt file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a content of string in spring mvc controller and I am saving that string into `.txt` file format in one of the specified path.
This was done Successfully, My problem is I have to add heading in that text file from controller and that should be bold and underlined.
I googled it for the solution but unable to find it. can anybody please suggest me in this regard?

Comment: Please provide an example of your code. Text files have no styles so you could not have *bold*, but there are markup that could be saved in text and will processed from viewer software, like the editor you use here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Agree with @MarioSantini, plain text files cannot have formatted characters (bold, underlined, italics etc).

Comment: Hi Mario, 
My .txt out put looks like this

Assignment : 
gggg
Now I am trying to change Assignment to Bold and  add underline to it. I am trying to do it from my Spring MVC controller.

Comment: @Nithin, have you read our comments above? plain text .txt files CANNOT have bold or underlined characters! It is not spring's problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will workout on some other issues. Thanks for your assistance.